# how to use pipes in condition matching in r?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am getting an error while trying to filter data in 1st df based on countries available in 2nd df by using pipe operator in conditional statement.

**Referencing countries df**

```
Overall_top5

########### output ###########

continent country gdpPercap

Africa  Botswana    8090        
Africa  Equatorial Guinea   20500       
Africa  Gabon   19600       
Africa  Libya   12100       
Africa  Mauritius   10900       
Americas    Canada  51600       
Americas    Chile   15100       
Americas    Trinidad and Tobago 17100
```

**main df**

```
gap_longer

########### output #############

country year gdpPercap continent

Australia   2019    57100   Oceania 
Botswana    2019    8090    Africa  
Canada  2019    51600   Americas    
Chile   2019    15100   Americas    
Denmark 2019    65100   Europe
```

**Error:** When I try below code it gives me errors:

```
gap_longer %>% 
  filter(year == 2019,
         country %in% Overall_top5 %>% select(country) )

Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`. x no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "logical" i Input `..1` is `country %in% Overall_top5 %>% select(country)`. Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

**How can I run this using pipes ?** I am able to run this using base R but don't know how to fix it using pipes .

```
gap_longer %>% 
  filter(year == 2019,
         country %in% Overall_top5$country )
```

---

Raw data

```r
Overall_top5 <- structure(list(continent = c("Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Americas", "Americas", "Americas"), country = c("Botswana", "Equatorial Guinea", "Gabon", "Libya", "Mauritius", "Canada", "Chile", "Trinidad and Tobago"), gdpPercap = c(8090L, 20500L, 19600L, 12100L, 10900L, 51600L, 15100L, 17100L)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
gap_longer <- structure(list(country = c("Australia", "Botswana", "Canada", "Chile", "Denmark"), year = c(2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L), gdpPercap = c(57100L, 8090L, 51600L, 15100L, 65100L), continent = c("Oceania", "Africa", "Americas", "Americas", "Europe")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Thanks @r2evans for adding extra data !!!

Comment: FYI, it's common (in R) to use `read.table` for grabbing data from a question. Unfortunately, embedded spaces break that, requiring manual editing to make it something that can be easily parsed and used/tested. It's much better for the data to be in an unambiguous format originally; if there are no spaces, then this would work (though aesthetics might justify aligning columns); but when there are embedded spaces, `factor`s, `Date`s, `POSIXt`s, or similarly ambiguous or difficult-to-easily-parse elements, then `dput` (or programmatically with `data.frame(.)`) is the best way. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the info I will try this and is there a way to attach a csv file along with post ? sometimes there is really a need to reproduce the issue with real data.

Comment: There's no way to "attach" a file/attachment like there is for images, but you can paste relevant lines of any text file, whether source code, CSV, TSV, xml, whatever into a code-block, and it does really well for sample data. This can be used whether the problem is importing the data or not, since `read.csv(text="...")` works just as well as `structure(...)`, though if the problem is with the format of imported data, `structure(...)` (from `dput`) is still preferred, as it shows what you actually have at the time, not just on import.

Comment: Thanks @r2evans, I will surely try out these options from now on !!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you want to use `pull` rather than `select` as `select` will return a data frame rather than a vector (but that doesn't solve your problem).

Your problem comes from precedence. In your example, `%in%` is evaluated first, then `%>%`. To fix this, use parentheses.

```
gap_longer %>% 
  filter(
    year == 2019,
    country %in% (Overall_top5 %>% pull(country))
  )
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   country   year gdpPercap continent
#>   <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>    
#> 1 Botswana  2019      8090 Africa   
#> 2 Canada    2019     51600 Americas 
#> 3 Chile     2019     15100 Americas
```

Comment: isn't `gap_longer()` in the new *tidyr* package? I updated, but can't find it in my R session.

Comment: Thanks alot @Paul. Before posting I tried with () but didnt use pull() so it returned 0 rows .
```gap_longer %>% 
  filter(year == 2019,
         country %in% (Overall_top5 %>% select(country))). Thanks again !!

Comment: @DanielJachetta `gap_longer` is actually a longer form of latest gapminder dataset that i have created (downloaded from gapminder website)

Comment: oh yes, I see, gap_longer was the dataset, I was getting that confused with the function `pivot_longer()` thank you

Comment: Yes even i thought you assumed it as `pivot_longer()`

Answer (score 1):

Parenthesis problem.  Try:

```
gap_longer %>% 
    filter(year == 2019, country %in% Overall_top5$country) %>% 
    select(country)
```

or, if you want a vector of country names, not a data frame:

```
gap_longer %>% 
    filter(year == 2019, country %in% Overall_top5$country) %>% 
    pull(country)
```

Comment: Thanks @Art but it is returning `0 rows` and in other that returns `character(0)`. And @Paul answer is working absolutely fine

Comment: oops.  see my fix.

Comment: Yes it works now. Thanks for updating the right answer. I will keep this approach in mind as well.